# About direct limit of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G_i$ be sequence of groups for $i\in \mathbb N$ and Let $\phi_i$ be a monomorphism from $G_i$ to $G_{i+1}$.

Let $\Sigma$ be the direcet limits of $G_i$ under the embeddings of $\phi_i$.

Let $\varphi_i$ be another monomorphism from $G_i$ to $G_{i+1}$ s.t.

$$\phi_i(G_i)=\varphi_i(G_i)$$

i.e their image are same. (but not element wise).

If $\Sigma '$ is the direct limits of $G_i$ under the embeding of $\varphi_i$ then can we say that $\Sigma\cong \Sigma '$ ?

Comment: I found this similar to: If a direct limit exists, it is unique up to C-isomorphism

Comment: Clearly, if for all $i$, we had an automorphism $\theta_i:G_i\to G_i$ such that $\theta_{i+1}\circ\phi_i=\varphi_i$ (with $\theta_0=id_{G_0}$), then both whole diagrams $G_0\to G_1\to G_2\to \dots$ would be isomorphic, hence their limit would be isomorphic too.

So, for a first step towards a counterexample let's find $H\le G$ with an automorphism $\vartheta:H\to H$ that doesn't extend to an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Cross-posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198766/about-direct-limit-of-groups/198772#198772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple example (abelian torsion free of rank 2).

Let $G_i=\mathbf{Z}^2$, $\phi_i(x,y)=\phi(x,y)=(px,y)$ and $\varphi_i(x,y)=\varphi(x,y)=(py,x)$. Then $\Sigma_\phi=\mathbf{Z}[1/p]\times\mathbf{Z}$ while $\Sigma_\varphi=\mathbf{Z}[1/p]^2$ (note that $\varphi^2(x,y)=(px,py)$).

[Let us observe that the condition that $\phi_i$ and $\varphi_i$ have the same image is somewhat unstable, since it does not imply that $\phi_{i+1}\circ\phi_i$ and $\varphi_{i+1}\circ\varphi_i$ have the same image.]